# JSF - getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id') returns null

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("compId")` returns null for `outputLable` and `outputText`, but not for `inputText` and `inputHidden`.
Why is that and how do I get the value for outputLabel or outputText?

Comment: Why would you want to get the outputLabel and outputText values ? Those values are not submitted because they are not part of the user input/choices.

Comment: Yes, but I send them to the browser as hidden. I can't use inputHidden, because it doesn't work for me the way I need. I need to get that outputText/outputLabel value somehow

Comment: How do you set your label ?

Comment: @Christophe Roussy : First, I was using a inputHidden. And it resides inside a column. I have a value bind to the backing bean. Somehow when I clear the dataTable list, that inputHidden value does not get cleared. I need it to be cleared. So tried outputText with visible=true, and that works in the way I need, but I can't read its value like I posted. If you know how to pull it out, please tell me.

Comment: If you ask a new question for which you [incorrectly thought](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that this is the right solution, then we may be able to propose the right solution.

Comment: Have a look at this article: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-add-row-in-jsf-datatable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how [HTML](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/) works. Only [form elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) send their `name=value` pairs as HTTP request parameters, because their value can be controlled by the enduser.

For output labels and output texts this would not happen. It would not make any sense, because their value are usually not controlled by the enduser. Those values are usually already controlled by the webdeveloper. There's no point of sending a copy of them back if the server side **already** knows about them. If you're however allowing the enduser to change them in the client side by JavaScript means, then you should be adding a hidden input element (`<input type="hidden">`) and setting the changed value over there. Hidden inputs do also send their `name=value` pair as HTTP request parameter.

Comment: I was waiting for YOUR answer. I knew, I'm doing something wrong. Anyway can you tell me, if I use a binding, then is there a chance to get that value ?

Comment: There are many ways to extract developer-controlled data from the view. Which one the right is depends on the concrete functional requirement which is still unknown at that point. See also my comment on your question.

Comment: I used a different getter (different name) and return the previous value I used early, and I leave the new setter empty. And It works. I understood the way it works that only after read your answer. You saved me :). Thanks!

Comment: Although I still don't understand the concrete problem which you just solved, glad to be of help in some way :)

Comment: I'm using a dataTable and in each row has a suggestion box. When I add new record, it gives me early values. But in the back end, there are no such values. I used a hidden field. Based on that, I could validate that suggestion box. It works, but after when I cleared the dataTable value (whole records) then started to cache the hidden field too. My solution became a problem. Back end has no values, but html has. When I use a combo box, instead of suggestion box, there is no matter at all. My JSF knowledge is less than a month :( . I might design it in a wrong way.

Comment: So... that suggestion box is not a JSF component, but some homegrown HTML/JS code?

Comment: Yes. It is not a JSF one, but it uses inputText and selectItems. That suggestion box also fine if I use only one per a view. But in my application I use it as a singleton instance and use over and over again. Sometimes it may be the problem, and I don't like to initiate a new suggestion-box-backing-bean for each suggestion-box. I holds lot of records. That's why I need that kind of a component in the first place. Somehow its working now :)